# Create link in top navigation to course history

Tags: moodle

I'm trying to add a static link to the top navigation bar for the logged in users "Grade" page. Is there anyway to make this possible? Creating the link without the "user" parameter results in error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe you should be able to do this using the [Navigation API](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Navigation_API).

Something like:

```
$settingnode = $PAGE->navigation->find('grades', navigation_node::TYPE_CONTAINER);
$thingnode = $settingnode->add(get_string('Name of thing'), new moodle_url('/a/link/if/you/want/one.php'));
$thingnode->make_active();
```